# Program running fine locally, but when submit it encounters errors

Tags: python

```
# objective: look for "the lines", count the lines, extract floating point and compute average
try:
    fhand = open(input("File you'd like to open: "))
except:
    print("File not found.\n")
    quit()

total = 0.0
count = 0.0
numbers = ""
for lines in fhand:
    if lines.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        count += 1
        for words in lines: # turn string to float
            try:
                if words in "0123456789.":
                    numbers = numbers + words
                elif words not in "0123456789.":
                    total = total + float(numbers)
                    numbers = ""
            except:
                continue

print(f"Average spam confidence: {total/count}")
```

1. My code works in vscode but not in py4e and the value there says "Average spam confident: nan"
2. Edit: For error traceback there's I think I'll put an image here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJjLd.jpg
3. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include the full error traceback?

Comment: What is py4e?  I don't know what that is.

Comment: py4e == https://www.py4e.com/.  Use a debugger to find out what the values are for total and count.  Should be easy to spot.  You'd get NaN if count was zero, for example.  You assume that it's not.  Never comfort yourself with "It works in X but not Y."  Your code is wrong - figure out why.

Comment: Please edit the title to describe the problem, not your learning level.

Comment: `for words in lines:` doesn't loop over words, it loops over characters in the line.

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly print "nan" for the result of `total/count`.  If count is zero, that should raise a zero division error.

Comment: Your loop is a strange way to extract the number. Just use `numbers = float(lines.split()[1])`

Comment: @TamMarshall I'd never heard of py4e.com until today and decided to have a look. Some of the guidance there is comical. If I were you I'd avoid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor change to your original code, try to see if that can help you?  (done this *many years ago*... not sure it's the same format though)

Maybe just for your reference checking.  Let me know if any questions.

```py
for line in fhand: 
    if line.startswith(...... )       # same checking...
        space_pos = line.find(' ')    #
        num = float(line[space_pos +1: ])
        total +=  num
        count +=  1
print("Average spam confidence: ",  total/count)      #  try it and ask questions?
```